# Combining the value of GetLastError and a custom error message

Tags: c, windows, getlasterror

I have a function that returns a different DWORD value for each case there is an error. So I have the following defines:

```
#define ERR_NO_DB_CONNECTION    0x90000
#define ERR_DB_NOT_OPEN         0x90001
#define ERR_DB_LOCKED           0x90002
#define ERR_DB_CONN_LOST        0x90003
```

Now, I return those values when an error occurs. 
I need to also return the value of GetLastError in the same return.

No, I can't read it later.

I tried combining it different ways, eg:

```
return ERR_DB_NOT_OPEN + GetLastError();
```

and then extract the error by subtracting the value of ERR_DB_NOT_OPEN but since I need to use this in functions where there can be several return values it can get quite complex to do that.

Is there any way to achieve this? I mean, combine the value + GetLastError and extract them later?
Code is appreciated.

Thanks

Jess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381(VS.85).aspx), the system error codes max out at 15999 (0x3E7F). This means you have the entire upper word to play with. You'll need to shorten your error codes to fit into 4 hex digits, then you can use some Windows macros to combine and split them:

```
return MAKELPARAM(GetLastError(), ERR_DB_NOT_OPEN);

int lasterror = LOWORD(result);
int code = HIWORD(result);
```

Comment: That's not quite true. The upper bits are used to encode severity, facility, and so on. See winerror.h.

Comment: Those are only the currently existing error codes; Microsoft reserves the right to add new error codes in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is old, but just in case... Complementing Mark's answer. Following code region is available for you to define your own errors.

> Error codes are 32-bit values (bit 31 is the most significant bit).
>   Bit 29 is reserved for application-defined error codes; no system
>   error code has this bit set. If you are defining an error code for
>   your application, set this bit to indicate that the error code has
>   been defined by your application and to ensure that your error code
>   does not conflict with any system-defined error codes.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can combine them into a string (a char array) and then split them from the caller.